# linked list with template: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, linked-list

I'm trying to write a linked list. The nodes are defined like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
    T value;
    Node<T> *next;
};
```

With primitive types, my linkedlist works perfectly. But when I try to use it to store instances of a custom class, I get the error "call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of Node".

I believe the problem is that when I try to make a new node, I'm not initializing `value`, which is a `T`. But I'm not sure how to do that...

```
template<typename T>
Node<T> *LinkedList<T>::makeNewNode(T val)
{
    Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>;
    newNode->value = val
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know what your `T` is, I assume, it is not default-constructible. In this case, simply call the proper copy-constructor of `Node`:

```
template<typename T>
Node<T> *LinkedList<T>::makeNewNode(const T& val)
{
    return new Node<T>(val);

}
```

which, in turn, would require your `Node` class to have a constructor which accepts `T`:

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
    T value;
    Node<T> *next;
    Node(const T& value) : value(value), next(nullptr) { }
};
```

Comment: does this mean my T has to have a copy constructor?

Comment: @ahhhhhjulie, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `Node` should initialize the `value` field for example with:

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
    public:
        T value;
        Node<T> *next;
        Node(const T& value) : value(value), next(nullptr) { }
};
```

then when calling the constructor you provide the value directly:

```
template<typename T>
Node<T> *LinkedList<T>::makeNewNode(const T& val)
{
    Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>(val);
    return newNode;
}
```